# How to replace the NA for the specific date by mean of same date through out the time series in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe "df" containing rainfall time series

```
 str(df)
'data.frame':   10227 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Date : Date, format: "1990-01-01" "1990-01-02" "1990-01-03" ...
 $ Month: Ord.factor w/ 12 levels "Jan"<"Feb"<"Mar"<..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Year : num  1990 1990 1990 1990 1990 1990 1990 1990 1990 1990 ...
 $ stn1 : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ stn2 : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Day  : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 …
```

I want to fill the NAs of specific date with the mean of same date of all the year in the time series.

I have used the following code to create the mean of the days, however I am not able to impute it in my dataframe df.

```
library(dplyr)

Mean <- function(x) {mean(x, na.rm = T)}

daily_mean <- Rainfall[-1] %>% group_by(Month, Day) %>% 
  summarise_all(list(Mean))
```

the "daily_mean" dataframe looks like this

```
str(daily_mean)
Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 366 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ Month        : Ord.factor w/ 12 levels "Jan"<"Feb"<"Mar"<..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Day          : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Year         : num  2004 2004 2004 2004 2004 ...
 $ stn1         : num  1.31 0.54 1.57 1.41 0 ...
 $ stn2         : num  0.689 0.111 0 0 0 ...
```

Is there any way to impute the dataframe "df" from "daily_mean"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`group_by` `Month` and `Day` and `replace` `NA` values with `mean` of group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
   group_by(Month, Day) %>% 
   mutate_all(~replace(., is.na(.), mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Comment: Thank you @Ronak, It works but show the following message; `mutate_all()` ignored the following grouping variables:
Columns `Month`, `Day`
Use `mutate_at(df, vars(-group_cols()), myoperation)` to silence the message.

Comment: @VaskerSharma yes, since we are using `mutate_all` with `group_by` it is letting us know that it is not replacing with mean on grouped columns (`Month`, `Day`) which we don't want anyway. It is safe to ignore that warning. Or to be specific you can use as suggested in the warning message.  `df %>% 
  group_by(Month, Day) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~replace(., is.na(.), mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))`

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `na.aggregate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df %>%
   group_by(Month, Day) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(-group_cols()), na.aggregate)
```

---

Or if we use the `Mean` function

```
df %>%
    group_by(Month, Day) %>%
     mutate_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~ case_when(is.na(.) ~ Mean(.), TRUE ~ .))
```

---

Or using `split` with `na.aggregate`

```
nm1 <- setdiff(names(df), c("Month", "Day"))
df[nm1] <- unsplit(lapply(split(df[nm1], df[c("Month", "Day")], drop = TRUE), 
        na.aggregate), df[c("Month", "Day")])
```